# How do I declare this type as a return value?

Tags: c#, linq

I am running a Linq query on a CSV file like this:

```
var csvData = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
               .Skip(1)
               .Select(x => x.Split(','))
               .Select(x => new
               {
                    IDOrderAlpha = x[0].Replace("\"", ""),
                    IDOrder = x[1].Replace("\"", ""),
                    AddressCompany = x[2].Replace("\"", ""),
                    Address1 = x[3].Replace("\"", ""),
                    Address2 = x[4].Replace("\"", ""),
                    AddressCity = x[5].Replace("\"", ""),
                    AddressState = x[6].Replace("\"", ""),
                    AddressZip = x[7].Replace("\"", ""),
                    AddressCountry = x[8].Replace("\"", ""),
                    ShipMethod = x[9].Replace("\"", ""),
                    ContactEmail = x[10].Replace("\"", ""),
                    ContactName = x[11].Replace("\"", ""),
                    ServiceRep = x[12].Replace("\"", ""),
                    CustomerPuchaseOrder = x[13].Replace("\"", ""),
               });
```

Now I would like to pass that to another function, but cannot figure out what the object type is for the return value. What should I specify (i.e. in the below example, what is `someType`)?:

```
static someType clearNoShip(someType csvData)
{
      // do work on csvData and return it
}
```

Comment: You do know that `this,"data, will",not` be parsed correctly, right? You might want to use an existing CSV library like [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire point of an anonymous type is that they are *anonymous*, aka "no name".

You can get around it by returning `dynamic` and working with weakly typed types, but that's ugly. Instead create a type that holds these fields and use

```
.Select(x => new MyType() { }
```

and return `MyType`

Answer (score 3):

It's an anonymous type.  They are *specifically* designed to be used only from within the scope in which they are created.  If you want to be passing that to another method that will act on the type then you should be creating a new named type, rather than using an anonymous type.

While it is *possible* to do this, all of the alternatives are going to be more work, and more problematic for you, than simply creating a new named type.